# Enabling virtual com port support in Platform Builder?

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, platform-builder

I have USB RFID reader and Win CE 6.0 OS. My device is TQ2440 (ARM).
The system is in CN language, the reader is available on '$device\COM10' port (After installing FTDI VCP drivers). Everything is fine.

As CN language is not acceptable, I want to build own OS on Platform Builder. I have BSP provided by the device and OS supplier. After building system and installing drivers, I don't see any USB device (COM) which I can use (like '$device\COM10'?).

My question is, which option should I turn in Platform Builder on, so I could use the reader.
As far as I know it's called virtual com port support? But i can't find such an option in PB.

USB Host and Function is checked, so it should be installed...

Answer (score 1):

You will need the windows ce drivers from ftdi.  They can be downloaded here:

http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm

You can then add them to the platform os build.